# Apache (htaccess) redirect loop http https

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

We are experiencing a redirect loop on Wordpress homepage and I have no idea where does it come from, we switched the URL to http://www to https://.

Here is the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

http://scrybs.com is redirecting to http://www.scrybs.com and http://www.scrybs.com is causing a redirect loop...

I tried to deactivate all plugins, remove htaccess file, none of those worked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the first rule. Change `^.*$` to `^(.*)$`, so that `$1` actually contains something.

Comment: @MikeRockett The issue happens before htaccess calling...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RewriteRules for the HTTP to HTTPS redirect.  Change it to have the HTTP (port 80) virtual host redirect to the HTTPS (port 443) virtual host and put all your configuration in the HTTPS (port 443) configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost >
```

Ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html

Then, remove these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You may want to restore the **www** configuration, but without the HTTPS update.

Comment: Do I have to add these lines on my .htacess file or server side? It seems that my issue is appearing before calling the .htaccess file....